# How to update head title after axios call in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a product page where i pass product id & based on that i call rest Api & after Api response i need to update title tag with product name. i am able to update title tag but in view source i get value as undefined or default value. So how to update title in the beginning so will get product name in view source. So that will be SEO friendly.

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data () {
    return {
      setTitle: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    axios.get('https://apiurl.com/testing.json')
          .then((response) => {
            this.setTitle = response.data            
          })
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: `${this.setTitle.product_name} product name`,
      meta: [
        {
          vmid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content:
            "hello world, this is an example of adding a description with vueMeta"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Is it possible if in my project SSR is false?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `asyncData` hook provided by nuxt which runs before creating the page (you don't need to define `setTitle` in `data` option ) and replace `metaInfo` by `head` :

```
export default{
 name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
 async asyncData() {
    const {data} = await  axios.get('https://apiurl.com/testing.json')
    return { setTitle:data} // without defining data option
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: `${this.setTitle.product_name} product name`,
      meta: [
        {
          vmid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content:
            "hello world, this is an example of adding a description with vueMeta"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its working fine, but i want to know one more thing, i have my axios code in another method. So i just i want to call this method from asyncData function. How should i do it. Could you please help me on this. 
want to use below axios call in another method & just need to call the function from asyncData
`const {data} = await  axios.get('https://apiurl.com/testing.json')`

Comment: As i have checked in my project SSR is false, So it does not update title tag on Api response. I cannot change SSR as true as impact whole project. Do you know with SSR false how we can update title tag? is it possible?